# Rename primary key constraint in Teradata

Tags: teradata

Does Teradata have a way to rename a primary key constraint, rather than dropping it and recreating it? I'm using SP_RENAME for SQL Server and ALTER TABLE...RENAME CONSTRAINT for Oracle, but I don't know a corresponding command for Teradata.

Comment: If not, can the constraint be dropped and recreated (on Teradata v12) or does the entire table need to be dropped and recreated?

Comment: Constraint can be dropped and recreated while leaving the table alone. Haven't found anything on renaming yet.

Answer (score 1):

no, renaming is not possible in Teradata but as already stated you can drop the constraint and recreate it