# Rename the constraint of a possibly referenced primary key in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, primary-key

Is it safe to use this command just like that, even though the table might be referenced from other tables as foreign key?

```
ALTER INDEX foo_pkey RENAME TO pk__foo__id;
```

I have just tried it and it seems OK, but I have heard it is necessary to drop foreign keys, rename pkey (drop/recreate) and re-reference the table again.

---

In case it is not that easy, is there a way how to find all referencing tables, drop their fkeys, alter the index and atach them again in one SQL?

Here is what I am using to find tables and their fkeys referencing my table:

```
SELECT
    tc.table_name, tc.constraint_name, kcu.column_name,
    ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name,
    ccu.column_name AS foreign_column_name
FROM
    information_schema.table_constraints AS tc
    JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
      ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
    JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
      ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND ccu.table_name ='foo';
```

Comment: Using `ALTER INDEX ... RENAME TO ...` should be perfectly safe. Where did you hear otherwise?

Comment: @JoshKupershmidt Other databases, such as this one I found in SE [_Teradata_](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19982/rename-primary-key-constraint-in-teradata) require to do a drop/recreate and I couldn't find anything about it in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why Teradata has that limitation, but `ALTER INDEX ... RENAME TO ...` should be fine in PostgreSQL even when other tables have foreign keys depending on that index. PostgreSQL has fairly sophisticated tracking of such dependencies -- for example, if you tried to do `ALTER TABLE foo DROP CONSTRAINT foo_pkey;` you would see a complaint like:

> ERROR:  cannot drop constraint foo_pkey on table foo because other objects depend on it
>
> DETAIL: constraint bar_fkey on table bar depends on index foo_pkey
>
> HINT: Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.

You can also see in the [pg_constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html) table (e.g. via `SELECT * FROM pg_constraint WHERE conname = 'bar_fkey'` for some referencing foreign key `bar_fkey`) that PostgreSQL is internally tracking this dependency by the **OID** (in particular, the `conindid` column in `pg_constraint`) of the index rather than the name of the index. The OID of the index does not change when you use `ALTER INDEX ... RENAME TO ...`, which is how Postgres avoids becoming confused by the rename.